# Setting IP address in Linux using c++

Tags: c++, networking

I want to set my IP, subnet, DHCP addresses but I need to do it by using c++. I have researched on the internet and tried some code. Unfortunately, it didn't work. And one more thing it supposes to be secure to run it, I mean I cannot use functions that need privilege like system() and so on. Is there any advice you can give me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main()
{
    char ip_address[15];
    int fd;
    struct ifreq ifr;
    struct sockaddr_in *addr;

    /*Read IP Address*/
    printf("Enter Ip Address: ");
    scanf("%s",ip_address);

    /*AF_INET - to define network interface IPv4*/
    /*Creating soket for it.*/
    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    /*AF_INET - to define IPv4 Address type.*/
    ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_INET;

    /*eth0 - define the ifr_name - port name
    where network attached.*/
    memcpy(ifr.ifr_name, "eth0", IFNAMSIZ-1);

    /*defining the sockaddr_in*/
    addr=(struct sockaddr_in *)&ifr.ifr_addr;

    /*convert ip address in correct format to write*/
    inet_pton(AF_INET,ip_address,&addr->sin_addr);

    /*Setting the Ip Address using ioctl*/
    ioctl(fd, SIOCSIFADDR, &ifr);
    /*closing fd*/
    close(fd);

    printf("IP Address updated sucessfully.\n");

    /*Getting the Ip Address after Updating.*/

    /*clear ip_address buffer with 0x20- space*/
    memset((unsigned char*)ip_address,0x20,15);
    ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr);
    /*Extracting Ip Address*/
    strcpy(ip_address,inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&ifr.ifr_addr)->sin_addr));

    printf("Updated IP Address is: %s\n",ip_address);

    return 0;
}
```

This code is what I have tried so far. After I run this I check `ifconfig` but nothing is changed.

Comment: Well, perhaps you should check the return values from all the system calls you're making. That's a very good habit to acquire on, as early as possible: don't just make a wish that all your system calls work, and assume so. Always check the return values from every system call. That, and check the manual pages of all the system calls you're making, to see if you have to be root in order to make them.

Comment: If you don't have privileges, I doubt if you can set the IP address of the networking device.

Comment: You don't need privileges to call system().

Comment: Even *if* you could change the IP address of your computer to a random value, how would that affect the rest of the network? For example, if you choose the same address as I have, would that suddenly redirect my internet traffic to you? Hope not.  :-)

Comment: Even if i do not need privileges, there are still some security problems in system() function.

Comment: You are doing it the right way.  Most likely ioctl is returning an error which you are failing to check.